# SQL Case Order By specific order

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, case

Ok, I asked something similar before, but I've researched it and haven't found this specifically.
I have a table that I need sorted on fields OptionName(NVarChar) and IsActive(BIT).

I need the results to be in the following order for a DDL:

```
Option A
Option B
Option C
Options that are Active, by OptionName ASC 
Option D
Options that are Inactive, by OptionName ASC
```

So far I have

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN PortalName = 'Company, Inc' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         CASE WHEN PortalName = 'Setup' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
         CASE WHEN PortalName = 'Daily Routine' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END,
         CASE WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN 3 ELSE 4 END, 
         CASE WHEN PortalName = 'Master Option' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END,
         PortalName ASC
```

But this returns the results as:

```
Option A
Option B
Option C
Option D
Options that are Active, by OptionName ASC 
Options that are Inactive, by OptionName ASC
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Got an answer: CASE WHEN PortalName = 'Master Option' THEN 9999 ELSE 5 END

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got an answer: CASE WHEN PortalName = 'Master Option' THEN 9999 ELSE 5 END

Comment: why you had entered 9999. is it indicate column number...? then column no.9999 does n't exist

Answer (score 2):

try,

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN PortalName = 'Company, Inc' THEN 0 
              WHEN PortalName = 'Setup' THEN 1 
              WHEN PortalName = 'Daily Routine' THEN 2 
              WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN 3 
              WHEN PortalName = 'Master Option' THEN 4 
         ELSE 5 END,
         PortalName ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, that made it cleaner, but it put Option D alphabetically in the set of Active options.

Comment: @NJohns: Try swapping `WHEN IsActive = 1` and `WHEN PortalName = 'Master Option'` (entire lines) in this solution.

Answer (score 1):

consider each part of the order by as a different column... Apply a case to each component.  Get the first part first... then the second part.  If it doesn't apply to the second part, just have it always the same value... something like...

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN PortalName = 'Company, Inc' THEN 1
       WHEN PortalName = 'Setup' THEN 2
       WHEN PortalName = 'Daily Routine' THEN 3
       WHEN PortalName = 'Master Option' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END,
  CASE WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
  PortalName ASC
```

Comment: Still not working. Mybe I will just see if this doesn't need to be a requirement ? :)